rsync without encryption/with light encryption, critical sshd_config
I have a "HDD VPS" with Debian bullseye, a lot of storage space, but not a lot of CPU power. FTP from this storage space goes at 10-12 MB/s. This is limited by HDD read speed; the speed (of an unencrypted transfer to a machine in the same datacentre) halved when an md5sum was running and reading the same large file.
However rsync over SSH goes at ~2 MB/s, clearly limited by CPU. So, I want to enable no encryption or else CPU-light encryption (arcfour, I guess). The data is not confidential, but I'd rather not rely on FTP or RSH because of plain-text passwords.
Answers around Stackexchange point to adding a Ciphers line to sshd_config with options like none and arcfour256. However, my only access to this server is via ssh. So if I bungle up sshd_config I end up completely locked out of the server.
I see a few potential ways out of this but don't know how to implement any of them; other suggestions would also be very welcome.

How do I test that my change to sshd_config won't make sshd inaccessible? (Other than replicating the configuration in a local VM). Also, examples of exact Ciphers lines would be appreciated as there are none in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on the server.

Is there a way to make rsync work by starting the remote rsync via ssh (so, still using ssh for authentication), but using an unencrypted protocol with the remote rsync and not the encrypted ssh channel?


For reference, from ssh -vv output:
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr



You can always spin up another instance of sshd running its own config file on its own port. Once you got that working, replace your "actual" sshd config (or just keep it running 'til you got the files, then stop it).

10-12 MB would rather sound like limited to 100 Mb – either artificially or by network bandwidth (so, in a VPS, that's artificial, because your network interface isn't dedicated hardware, but a software-visible function)

Are your measurements 10-12Mb/s and 2Mb/s, or 10-12MB/s and 2MB/s? Really important difference just need to understand which

Megabytes per second, not megabits.

I found out it's the disk speed when I was copying a large file off using FTP to the very same datacentre - so no MITM concerns - while at the same time running an MD5 calculation of the same file on the same source server. Rate was 5 Mb/s. I cancelled the MD5, rate rose to 10 Mb/s. As the MD5 was done locally on the server and FTP is not really affected by CPU load, the bottleneck was disk I/O.

OK. You've just increased the throughput by almost x10. Mb is megabits, MB is megabytes. It's a really important differentiation

You could run rsync --daemon on the remote. This only accepts data without encryption. You might still try adding compression to see if it goes faster. There is an optional user and password authentication that uses a weak 128 bit MD4 based  challenge response.
But you can also limit incoming connections to a given list of IP
addresses, or set of hostnames.
You configure which port the server listens on, and which parts of the filesystem can be written to, or read from. rsync --daemon can run as root, or as an ordinary user for more limited access. Often a one-off rsync --daemon is started from an ssh login, inheriting the ssh connection, but that is not what you want. Just avoid adding option --server, which is how rsync knows it should continue over the ssh connection.
See man rsyncd.conf and the rsync man page sections on DAEMON mode.


Is there a way to make rsync work by starting the remote rsync via ssh (so, still using SSH for authentication), but using an unencrypted protocol with the remote rsync and not the encrypted SSH channel?

Encryption helps against man-in-the-middling. If you think your shell deserves encryption (and I'd 100% agree with that), so would the rsync protoocol, because clearly, someone using the rsync protocol's transfer feature in a direction that puts their files on your server in a MITM attack gives them arbitrary access (e.g. they could modify your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. Game over.).
So, unencrypted or weakly encrypted is not an option. Luckily, encryption isn't that expensive anymore. Your mileage might vary – there's really under-equipped VPS'es in CPU terms – but in my experience, the compression part is often what limits your transfer speed. You might want to check --compress-choice in your rsync man page (and if your rsync doesn't support that, it might be worth trying to `ssh -o Compression=no yourhost 'sh -c 'tar cf - file1 file2… | zstd -1' | zstd -d | tar xf -' or similar, to compress manually on the fly, not through SSH.

I tried now with --compress-choice=none and I'm not getting a significant improvement. Of course, FTP with a throwaway user/password created for this purpose would do something, but is this the only option?

It's not even an option, because it has the same security issue as rsync without encryption; someone could modify arbitrary files on your server. With FTP (in active mode), they wouldn't even have to man-in-the-middle (FTP is really really old and bad. that has been known forever; FTP is really more of a "yeah we hacked this together, mostly to show off that we know how to use NCP/TCP, please don't rely on it" solution – from 1971). Encryption is simply not optional when allowing file access. If encryption is the limiting factor for speed, well, then that's the speed you can achieve.
